# Bash - trying to read multiple files and print based on line

Tags: bash, shell

So here is my code that almost works but doesn't stop when it should.

```
function quit {
     exit
}
     for file in `ls /var/tmp/animals/ | grep -v animals`
       do
         cat $file | awk '/foo/ { print "OK" } !/foo/ { print "NOK"}'

     done
quit
```

It reads the files in the directory /var/tmp/animals and if the file contaions the word foo it prints OK on the line if it doesn't it prints NOK on the line.

It sorta of works as for the 4 files in the directory it works fine, but then it doesn't stop and continues on for 20 more lines of printing NOK and OK randomly. There are only 4 files in the directory. Could anyone provide any insight as to why this is happening?

Comment: 1. Don't parse `ls`; use `find` instead. 2. Avoid useless use of `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `awk` runs your expression once for each line, not once for each file. Here is the fix.

You need replace this line:

```
cat $file | awk '/foo/ { print "OK" } !/foo/ { print "NOK"}'
```

to

```
grep -l "foo" $file >/dev/null && echo "OK" || echo  "NOK"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do this pretty easily in one line

```
find /var/tmp/animals/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -not -name '*animal*' -exec bash -c 'grep -q "foo" "$0" && echo "OK" || echo "NOK" ' {} \;
```

And if you were to use a `for` loop, use bash wildcard globbing rather than parsing [ls](/questions/tagged/ls), e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /var/tmp/animals/*; do
  if [[ -f $file && $file != *animal* ]]; then
    grep -q "foo" "$file" && echo "OK" || echo "NOK"
  fi
done
```

And specifically the reason your way doesn't work is it's testing every line, not every file.